# Take a polynomial to a Taylor Series to a functional form

Tags: taylor-expansion, regression

I am analyzing data from an experiment and have found a polynomial that fits the data nicely (minimum degree of 6) and I would like to find a function in a simpler form that fits the data (I am thinking a polynomial term multiplied by an exponential will be the functional form).  In order to do this I was thinking that I could convert my polynomial of 6+ terms to a Taylor series and that Taylor series to a "nicer" function.

Is this possible?  Or is there a better approach? Is there a method or online resource to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that approach. I would just fit a lower-order polynomial to the data, and compare the $R^2$ values. If your $R^2$ value stays really high, and the graph of the poly versus the data still looks good, then just go with that.

Comment: This is my sure-thing approach, but the data looks eerily like a "nice" function hence my curiosity.  Thank you for your help, I will likely default to this analysis.

Comment: Could you show the data or a plot of them ? Fitting with polynomials of high degree is never a good idea for a physical problem. By the way, could you describe the experiment in words ?